# How to convert particular text of a webpage into hindi using css or script

Tags: php

I want to convert particular text into hindi language using css or script in php language.I have been continuously trying to do this but i am unable to do this.

Comment: use google translator..

Comment: @Pradeep Please edit your question to be more clear of what you want. Do you want it via PHP, or a JavaScript asynchronous request when someone types something into a textbox, etc.

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

CSS is for design. You cannot use CSS to dynamically translate texts. You will need to do this via script. You can do it via google translate. A very simple example is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p>Hello everybody!</p>

<p>Translate this page:</p>

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

<p>You can translate the content of this page by selecting a language in the select box.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_google_translate

This will translate the whole page, true, but you can exclude items from translation by adding the class=`"notranslate"` to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing Google Translate into your website so users can translate into any language they use. Start at https://translate.google.com/manager/website/.

Comment: Not whole website, i want particular text using css or script.